# How to install erpnext on Windows

Tags: mariadb, erp, erpnext

I have installed ERPNext on Ubuntu, now I have a specific requirement where I want to install it on Windows OS.

I have download the following Pre requisites. 
1. Python 2.7 
2. MariaDB

What is the correct procedure to install erpnext on windows. ?

Answer (score 10):

`ERPNext` isn't compatible with `Windows`.
How ever you can **install it in Windows using `Virtual Machine`** 
So

**VM:**

Install a `Virtual Machine` on `Microsoft Windows`
By following these [instruction](http://www.howtogeek.com/56158/beginner-how-to-create-a-virtual-machine-in-windows-7-using-virtual-pc/)

After that follow these steps

**Installation Steps:**

1. Install `WAMPserver` from  [here](http://www.wampserver.com/en/download.php)
2. Install Python from [here](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/python-2.7.2.msi)
3. Install Setup tools from [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)
4. Configure `httpd.conf`
5. Replace shebang lines to your python directory.
6. Run `install.py`

*Good Luck*

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I already installed it on VM (ubuntu), and am looking for a way to install it on Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

ERPNext isn't compatible with windows yet, as it uses some unix utilities.

Answer (score 0):

It was not possible previously but due to the addition of the powerful WSL it is possible, however, following the docs doesn't result in the complete installation as they are outdated.

Use this guide to install it in WSL - 2, ubuntu:

https://discuss.frappe.io/t/guide-how-to-install-erpnext-v14-on-linux-ubuntu-step-by-step-instructions/92960#four-instal-curl-node-npm-and-yarn-6

**NOTE**: The installation process is relatively simpler on Windows 11 and WSL, in win 10 you **might** have to change some minor settings along the process that are unique to your system. However, it is possible to install it on both Win 10 & 11, So don't give up easily.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using windows subsystem for linux and carry the steps of installing on linux in commandline of linux.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. It's pretty generic, can you give more of an explanation?